# Create grep command dynamic and run from variable

Tags: grep

I am trying to create regex dynamicly and then run it, this is part of script

```
...
param="egrep $2 $1"
shift
shift
while [ $# -ne 0 ]
do
param="$param""|egrep $1"
shift
done
$param // here i get error
...
```

But echo for $param seems to me ok

.P F1 a b c // run script

```
egrep a F1| egrep b| egrep c
```

What should I do in order to run $param correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
eval $param
```

Answer (score 0):

try: eval $cmd

---